# If I combine a factory-producing factory with a computer, did I just create life?

Tags: life

Consider building a mobile factory, capable of mining resources, powering its processes with solar energy, creating imperfect copies of itself, replacing its own parts and to some degree adapt its processes to its environment (e.g. use wood when there is lots wood). It's also computer controlled, to move around according to environmental parameters (e.g. abundancy of resources, weather). Is that thing alive?

Comment: note people are working on self-replicating 3d printers - http://3dprint.com/57188/big-red-self-replicating/

Answer (score 2):

The definition of "life" is not actually agreed upon.  It's meaning is too steeped in religious implications to get 100% agreement.

Even within science, the definition of "life" is not fully agreed upon.  The closest agreement seen is described in the Wikipdia article on [Life](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Life):

> Since there is no unequivocal definition of life, the current
>   understanding is descriptive. Life is considered a characteristic of
>   something that exhibits all or most of the following
>   traits:
>
> - Homeostasis: Regulation of the internal environment to maintain a constant state; for example, electrolyte concentration or sweating to
>     reduce temperature.
> - Organization: Being structurally composed of one or more cells — the basic units of life.
> - Metabolism: Transformation of energy by converting chemicals and energy into cellular components (anabolism) and decomposing organic
>     matter (catabolism). Living things require energy to maintain internal
>     organization (homeostasis) and to produce the other phenomena
>     associated with life.
> - Growth: Maintenance of a higher rate of anabolism than catabolism. A growing organism increases in size in all of its parts, rather than
>     simply accumulating matter.
> - Adaptation: The ability to change over time in response to the environment. This ability is fundamental to the process of evolution
>     and is determined by the organism's heredity, diet, and external
>     factors.
> - Response to stimuli: A response can take many forms, from the contraction of a unicellular organism to external chemicals, to
>     complex reactions involving all the senses of multicellular organisms.
>     A response is often expressed by motion; for example, the leaves of a
>     plant turning toward the sun (phototropism), and chemotaxis.
> - Reproduction: The ability to produce new individual organisms, either asexually from a single parent organism, or sexually from two
>     parent organisms. or "with an error rate below the
>     sustainability threshold."
>
> These complex processes, called physiological functions, have
>   underlying physical and chemical bases, as well as signaling and
>   control mechanisms that are essential to maintaining life.

By these behaviors, I believe your machine would qualify as "alive."  However, it may be harder to convince everybody of this, for not everybody agrees that these mere biological behaviors are sufficient for "life."

Interestingly, it might be easier to achieve the label "sentient" than "alive" because "alive" has so many connotations associated with it.

Answer (score 1):

There are many definitions of life. But according at least to one definition, yes you will have created life - you don't even need the computer, as long as the mobile factory you created is self replicating and self repairing.

According to Erwin Schrodinger - famous physicist and anti-cat bigot - living systems are those physical systems which are capable of maintaining or decreasing their own entropy. This is in contrast to most inanimate physical systems, which because of the second law of thermodynamics, tend to always increase their entropy.

The self replicating mobile factory you described (essentially following Von Neuman's kinematic model) does maintain or decrease its own entropy, so by Schrodinger's definition, is alive.

Comment: Anti-cat bigot, ROFL!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Like a Von Neumann's kinematic model? If so I wouldn't consider it to be alive if it did not choose if it wanted to replicate or move on. If it is simply programmed to create more of itself it is only a mimic of life with the intelligence of it's creators being perceived by an observer.

Comment: What is a Von Neumann machine?? Do you mean a machine with the Von Neumann architecture? The IAS machine? Neither is directly an example of a machine with the specifications from the question. Edit: maybe you mean Von Neumann's kinematic model?

Comment: Machine, probe architecture they are all the same idea and all match the machine described in this question

Comment: The Von Neumann architecture does _not_ match that description, and neither does the IAS. The Von Neumann architecture is simply a CPU architecture with data and program in the same memory, nothing AI about that. In fact, you are likely to own several machines with a Von Neumann architecture (computer, phone, navigation system, perhaps even in your oven).

Comment: Unfortunately that answer presupposes free will; a determinist would argue that all life is programmed anyway.